# Converting SQL Server recovery model simple to full

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with a recovery model of simple.

Monthly we have:

- Total number of insert is 2196716
- Total number of delete is 639542
- Total number of update is 4203398

Now we are changing this server to active – active cluster environment.

Automatically recovery model change to full.

Above count’s are fine with recovery model fine? Any action required to take?

Comment: Why do you think because you are moving to a cluster environment the database `automatically changes to full recovery`?

Comment: we are changing to recovery model to full.. thanks

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking or looking for with your question. 2 million inserts `a month` is not a high amount of activity to me. You are aware of the changes required to your backup scheme going to FULL recovery model? Outside of that I don't know what else you are looking to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BOL says about recovery model that

> [Recovery models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189275.aspx) are designed to control transaction log
>   maintenance. A recovery model is a database property that controls how
>   transactions are logged, whether the transaction log requires (and
>   allows) backing up, and what kinds of restore operations are
>   available.

Please note that recovery model controls amount of logging in transaction log file and in case of disaster how much data you can recover. It has no relation to amount of inserts or updates or number of column in you table.

You can keep simple recovery model if you do not require point in time recovery. You can take full and differential backup in simple recovery model. If you want to change recovery model to full then make sure you take regular transaction log backups after changing recovery model. Changing recovery model should depends on how much data loss you can afford or agreed between you and client basically the RPO and RTO.